# How to pass a result of a function into a sub call?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with the following code. When stepping through it, both using the Sub name with no parameter parenthesis and using Call with parenthesis have the same behavior. Likewise, removing the ByRef makes no difference.

Vba enters the SetRange, sets the return to a Range, and ends, but then the next step is not entering ColumnToUpper. That is, when it hits the block of calls to ColumnToUpper, it just enters SetRange a bunch of times, but never enters any of the ColumnToUpper Subs.

```
'Beginning of main Sub
    ColumnToUpper SetRange(data, "Last Name")
    Call ColumnToUpper(SetRange(data, "First Name"))
    'more calls
End Sub

Sub ColumnToUpper(ByRef rng As Range)
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
        rng(i) = UCase(rng(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Function SetRange(tbl As ListObject, hdr As String) As Range
    SetRange = Range(tbl.Name + "[" + hdr + "]")
End Function
```

Of course, I could set a Range variable, and set it between each call to the other function, but I would prefer a more elegant method. Note, I am not just doing a huge block of known columns just being set to upper (as I could use one large range), but I narrowed it down to this easy to digest and still failing example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You want to use `&` for concatenation not `+`
2. You need to Set Objects:

> `Set SetRange ...`

So:

```
Function SetRange(tbl As ListObject, hdr As String) As Range
    Set SetRange = tbl.Parent.Range(tbl.Name & "[" & hdr & "]")
End Function
```

---

The fact that you did not get an error pointing at the `Set` issue means you have poor error handling.  Most likely you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code and it is bypassing the error and returning nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to use `&` instead of `+` for concatenation? In my experience, they work well interchangeably.

Comment: It is the same as always declaring the parent object to any Range object.  It is good practice.  If you wnat to concatenate use `&` if you want to sum use `+` that way you do not get them mixed up when the user puts numbers in two cells and you wanted to concatenate those cells and not add.  It will save you headache as the users do stupid things.

Comment: Ah, I get that. Thanks for clarification, just making sure there wasn't any performance consideration I may have been missing out on like the good ol' `$`.

Comment: Got it. Both forgot to use Set, and assumed On Error only applied to the next line!

Comment: @UnfortunatelyEvil nope, it stays in effect till you stop it with `On Error Goto 0`